# If we give grant to the views from a particular user where view and table not present ,will automatically grant to the table applied automatically

Tags: sql, oracle, view, datatable, oracle11g

Once grant is provided to the view for a particular user ,will it automatically give grant to the underlying table of the view in Oracle??

Related to Oracle View

Comment: A grant on the view will only allow access to the table using the view. The user will not be able to select directly from the table.

Answer (score 0):

No (as pmdba commented); that's the *beauty* of it.

I'm currently connected as Scott:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
```

This is my table:

```
SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        840                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

14 rows selected.
```

View selects only subset of columns and rows from that table:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2    select ename, job
  3    from emp
  4    where deptno = 10;

View created.
```

Grant `select` privilege to another user, Mike:

```
SQL> grant select on v_emp to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as Mike:

```
SQL> connect mike/pwd@orcl
Connected.
```

Select from that view works - I can see only what view returns:

```
SQL> select * from scott.v_emp;

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
CLARK      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
MILLER     CLERK
```

Just looking at the view, I have no idea which table(s) it is based on; I can describe it:

```
SQL> desc scott.v_emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
```

I can see it in `all_objects`:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type, created, status
  2  from all_objects
  3  where owner = 'SCOTT'
  4    and object_name = 'V_EMP';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         CREATED  STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------- -------- -------
V_EMP                          VIEW                09.03.23 VALID

SQL>
```

Nothing in `all_source`, though:

```
SQL> select text
  2  from all_source
  3  where owner = 'SCOTT'
  4    and name = 'V_EMP';

no rows selected
```

but OK - I *know* it is the `emp` table so - let's try to select directly from it:

```
SQL> select * from scott.emp;
select * from scott.emp
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

As expected, that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for commenting in detail 